# How to Create New User in Mikrotik Using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mikrotik

I am trying to add new user using Mikrotik PHP API in Laravel. I can use the API for other usage (like view user information) but when I try to create new user, it gives me nothing, even no error, just redirect me to intended page.

My route is

```
Route::post('/isp/addUser', 'MainController@addUser');
```

My Form request is

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('MainController@addUser') }}">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   @foreach ($networks as $network)
        <input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="{{ $user->name }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="{{ $network->ip }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{ $network->m_username }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="{{ $network->m_password }}">
   @endforeach
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm text-uppercase">
                <strong>add</strong>
        </button>
 </form>
```

My Controller method is

```
public function addUser(Request $request) {
        $API = new routeros_api();
        $API->user_name = $request->user_name;
        $API->ip = $request->ip;
        $API->user = $request->user;
        $API->pass = $request->pass;

        if ($API->connect($request->ip, $request->user, $request->pass)){
          $API->comm("/ppp/secret/add/name={{ $API->user }}/password=123456/service=ppoe/profile=1-MBPS");
          $API->disconnect();
        }

        return redirect('/isp');
    }
```

This is not even giving any error, so I am not getting any clue. I think I am not sending the request properly, but got no clue how to do it.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but does Laravel's template strings work inside controller methods? You're using it in the $API->comm() argument

Comment: I am also not sure. but I have no clue what to do :(

Comment: nice question tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for creating user you should send

```
$API->comm('/user/add',['name'=>$username,'password'=>$password,'group'=>'read']);
```

for more information you can check https://mikrotik.com/documentation/manual_2.4/System/Users.html

hope this helps

Comment: Although your answer does not solve the problem exactly, but it gives me the idea. I had to use array. Thanks